# Using summarize_at() with different funs() arguments... and other Qs related to margins of error

Tags: r, dplyr, standard-error, census, tidycensus

I am in the early stages of building a [package](https://gist.github.com/plnnr/dff1596356cbb71361bb00d8bd8ce61f) for using CHAS data from HUD. The data is basically repackaged ACS data that has been adjusted for regional variations in median family income, as well as having created custom tabulations. There are 18 tables at a few geographic levels from census tract at the smallest to states at the largest. Prior to 2013, the tract-level files were split based on place and county subdivision. That is to say, if a census tract is part in one city, part in another, and part in an unincorporated portion of a county, there would be three records for that census tract. In addition to the estimates each table produces, there are margins of error that are also reported. The table design looks like this:

```
GEOID    headvar_2    T8_est1    T8_est2    T8_est3 ... T8_moe1    T8_moe2    T8_moe3
1011.1   Tct 11, pt1  224        0          0           38         12          12
1011.2   Tct 11, pt2  etc..................
1013.1   Tct 13, pt1
1013.2   Tct 13, pt2
1014.0   Tct 14
```

The functions I've created basically clean up some of the header fields and can cast the data into long format, something that would look like this:

```
GEOID   headvar_2    table    var_type    var    value
1011.1  Tct 11, pt1  T8       est         1      224
1011.1  Tct 11, pt1  T8       est         2      0
1011.1  Tct 11, pt1  T8       est         3      0
1011.1  Tct 11, pt1  T8       moe         1      38
1011.1  Tct 11, pt1  T8       moe         2      12
1011.1  Tct 11, pt1  T8       moe         3      12
```

Above example is my desired format, but I'm not sure how to summarize it with dplyr at my current level of knowledge/skills in R, so they remain in wide format.

The real problem I'm running into is how to summarize (sum) the estimates where they are grouped by GEOID while simultaneously calculating the margin of error correctly AND preserving auxiliary header files. The [tidycensus](https://walkerke.github.io/tidycensus/articles/margins-of-error.html) package has a margin of error function that would be great if I could figure out how to use it.

```
cleanup_chas_tract <- function(chas_tract_data, year = 2015) {
  # Establish field names to help with field ordering
  refcols <- c('source', 'sumlevel', 'geoid', 'geoid2', 'name', 'st', 'cnty_plc')
  # Clean up header columns this way if year is after 2012
  if (year >= 2013) {
    chas_tract_data <- chas_tract_data %>% select(-tract)
    names(chas_tract_data)[names(chas_tract_data) == 'cnty'] <- 'cnty_plc'
    chas_tract_data$geoid2 <- substr(chas_tract_data$geoid, 8, 18)
    chas_tract_data <- chas_tract_data[, c(refcols, setdiff(names(chas_tract_data), refcols))]
    return(chas_tract_data)
  } 
  # Clean up header columns a little differently AND sum by split tract ID (geoid2) if 2009 to 2012
  else if (year %in% c(2009, 2010, 2011, 2012)) {
    chas_tract_data$name <- ''
    chas_tract_data$st <- substr(chas_tract_data$geoid, 8, 9)
    chas_tract_data$cnty_plc <- substr(chas_tract_data$geoid, 10, 12)
    chas_tract_data$geoid2 <- paste0(substr(chas_tract_data$geoid, 8, 12), substr(chas_tract_data$geoid, 23, 28))
    # chas_header <- chas_tract_data[1:7]
    chas_tract_data <- chas_tract_data[, c(refcols, setdiff(names(chas_tract_data), refcols))]
    chas_tract_data <- chas_tract_data %>%
      group_by(source, sumlevel, geoid2, name, st, cnty_plc) %>%
          summarize_at(vars(names(chas_tract_data[,8:length(names(chas_tract_data))])), funs(sum))
    return(chas_tract_data)
  } else return(warning("Error: Please select a valid year (2009 through 2015). CHAS 2000 under development."))
}
```

So this works to sum the estimates of the partial tracts, but it simply adds the margins of error together, which is not the correct way to do it. The problem seems to be that the tables require to separate functions to occur, but I am not sure how to structure my data to achieve this. One potential solution would be to subset just the moe columns with `grepl` and run a separate margin of error calculation and then re-combine the data. Any ideas out there on how to proceed? How to structure the data?

Comment: In my opinion, you've made it too long - `est` and `moe` should be separate columns. That will probably make it easier to work with I think (without looking in huge detail)

Comment: I think I'm struggling even if the estimate and moe are in separate columns, though that seems to be the format that tidycensus sum_moe() function accepts.